# QTP Error number -2147467259 when capturebitmap

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

This function used to work however now I see the message **"General run error"**, and then:

> ```
> msgbox Err.Number 
> The error number is **-2147467259**
> ```

The statement is like

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").Image("Image").CaptureBitmap "c:\temp\test.png",True
```

I don't recall anything changing and don't know what's causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution. Because now there is another screen connected to the computer. And Internet Explorer is launched on the second screen, not the principal one. So this statement cannot be well performed. I made IE opened in the principal screen, and problem sovled. But it's still strange that QTP can identify the webedits...

Comment: Can you share which version of QTP you are using? I believe that QTP11 supports multiple monitors.

Comment: @Motti, experience shows that the AUT must be on the primary screen for certain (if not all) operations.